# Cannot download artifact cas-server-core from https://mvnrepository.com/

Tags: java, maven-3

I have problem with downloading cas-server-core from https://mvnrepository.com/.When I try to add repository https://mvnrepository.com, maven ignore it and try to download artifact from artifactory, where it isnt present. My build.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.dhl.cas</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>cas</name>
    <version>3.0.10.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.cleverlance.dhl.spc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spc-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.3</version>
    </parent>

    <scm>
        <developerConnection>
            scm:svn:https://teamforge.dhl.com/svn/repos/SPL_APPL_TOOLBOX/cas-server/src/tags/cas-3.0.10.0
        </developerConnection>
        <connection>scm:svn:https://teamforge.dhl.com/svn/repos/SPL_APPL_TOOLBOX/cas-server/src/tags/cas-3.0.10.0
        </connection>
        <url>https://teamforge.dhl.com/svn/repos/SPL_APPL_TOOLBOX/cas-server/src/tags/cas-3.0.10.0</url>
    </scm>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0.4</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <cas.version>3.5.0</cas.version>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>Tomcat</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
        <ojdbc7>12.1.0.1.0</ojdbc7>
        <authentication.core.version>1.0.9.0</authentication.core.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.44</mysql.connector.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>dct.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sourcepath>${basedir}/dummy</sourcepath>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- add src/main/generated for maven -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/main/generated</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>


        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <version>2.0.2</version>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warName>cas</warName>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                            <nonFilteredFileExtension>xls</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        </nonFilteredFileExtensions>


                        <overlays>
                            <overlay>
                                <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
                                <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
                                <excludes>
                                    <!--                                    <exclude>**/spring-configuration,**/unused-spring-configuration,**/cas-servlet.xml</exclude> -->
                                    <exclude>WEB-INF/unused-spring-configuration/**</exclude>
                                    <exclude>WEB-INF/spring-configuration/**</exclude>
                                    <exclude>**/cas-servlet.xml</exclude>
                                    <exclude>**/deployerConfigContext.xml</exclude>
                                    <exclude>**/login-webflow.xml</exclude>
                                    <exclude>**/log4j.xml</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </overlay>
                        </overlays>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>-Duser.timezone=Etc/GMT</argLine>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <!--                <plugin> -->
                <!--                    <groupId> org.jasig.cas</groupId> -->
                <!--                    <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId> -->
                <!--                    <configuration> -->
                <!--                        <skip>true</skip> -->
                <!--                    </configuration> -->
                <!--                </plugin> -->


            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dhl.resp</groupId>
            <artifactId>authentication-core</artifactId>
            <version>${authentication.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CAS SSO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>

        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.inspektr</groupId>
            <artifactId>inspektr-audit</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.inspektr</groupId>
            <artifactId>inspektr-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.inspektr</groupId>
            <artifactId>inspektr-support-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- oracle driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>${ojdbc7}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- tools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SAML -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http client utils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <url>http://czcholstc000112.prg-dc.dhl.com:8272/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <url>http://czcholstc000112.prg-dc.dhl.com:8272/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>maven-release</name>
            <url>https://artifactory.dhl.com/maven-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <snapshots/>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>maven-snapshot</name>
            <url>https://artifactory.dhl.com/maven-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <snapshots/>
            <id>mavenrepository</id>
            <name>maven-repository</name>
            <url>https://mvnrepository.com/</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>mysql</id>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- mysql driver -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Can someone give me a point how to solve this issue? I think that it is enough to add repository in pom.xml, but It seems that there is some problem, which I dont know. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have wrong groupId

`<groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId> <artifactId>cas-server-core</artifactId> <version>6.5.5</version>`

For the group you have versions are listed here
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jasig.cas/cas-server-core

If you want 6.5.5 version, shouldn't it be this one?
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apereo.cas/cas-server-core/6.5.5

Comment: It looks like they moved/renamed indeed. The last news we can find referencing the old name is this: https://www.apereo.org/projects/cas/archive-new-jasig-cas-documentation-initiative-underway And the links on that site to Jasig.org redirect to apereo.org